# How can I prevent values from overlapping in a Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, synchronization, multiprocessing

I'm trying Python multiprocessing, and I want to use Lock to avoid overlapping variable 'es_id' values.

According to theory and examples, when a process calls lock, 'es_id' can't overlap because another process can't access it, but, the results show that es_id often overlaps.

How can the id values not overlap?

Part of my code is:

```
def saveDB(imgName, imgType, imgStar, imgPull, imgTag, lock): #lock=Lock() in main
    imgName=NameFormat(imgName) #name/subname > name:subname
    i=0
    while i < len(imgName):
        lock.acquire()  #since global es_id
        global es_id

        print "getIMG.pt:save information about %s"%(imgName[i])
        cmd="curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/kimhk/imgName/"+str(es_id)+" -d '{" +\
                        '"image_name":"'+imgName[i]+'", '+\
                        '"image_type":"'+imgType[i]+'", '+\
                        '"image_star":"'+imgStar[i]+'", '+\
                        '"image_pull":"'+imgPull[i]+'", '+\
                        '"image_Tag":"'+",".join(imgTag[i])+'"'+\
                        "}'"
        try:
                subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                print e.output
        i+=1
        es_id+=1
        lock.release()
```

...

```
#main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock = Lock()
    exPg, proc_num=option()

    procs=[]
    pages=[ [] for i in range(proc_num)]
    i=1

    #Use Multiprocessing to get HTML data quickly
    if proc_num >= exPg:  #if page is less than proc_num, don't need to distribute the page to the process.
            while i<=exPg:
                    page=i
                    proc=Process(target=getExplore, args=(page,lock,))
                    procs.append(proc)
                    proc.start()
                    i+=1
    else:
            while i<=exPg: #distribute the page to the process
                    page=i
                    index=(i-1)%proc_num    #if proc_num=4 ->  0 1 2 3
                    pages[index].append(page)
                    i+=1
            i=0
            while i<proc_num:
                    proc=Process(target=getExplore, args=(pages[i],lock,))#
                    procs.append(proc)
                    proc.start()
                    i+=1

    for proc in procs:
            proc.join()
```

execution result screen:

[image: image showing duplicate eids]

result is the output of **subprocess.call (cmd, shell = True)**. I use XPUT to add data to ElasticSearch, and es_id is the id of the data. I want these id to increase sequentially without overlap. (Because they will be overwritten by the previous data if they overlap)

I know XPOST doesn't need to use a lock code because it automatically generates an ID, but I need to access all the data sequentially in the future (like reading one line of files).

If you know how to access all the data sequentially after using XPOST, can you tell me?

Comment: How does the output shown in the screenshot relate to the code in your question? There's only one `print` in the code and the output doesn't look like it's a result of its execution.

Comment: The screen is the output of subprocess.call (cmd, shell = True). I sent XPUT to add data to ElasticSearch, and es_id is the id of the data.

I want these id to increase sequentially without overlap. (Because they will be overwritten by the previous data if they overlap)

Comment: What other code is accessing and changing the global `es_id`? All potentially concurrent access to it _must_ also use the lock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access a global variable with a lock, but global variables are different instances between processes.  What you need to use is a shared memory value.  Here's a working example.  It has been tested on Python 2.7 and 3.6:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import multiprocessing as mp

def process(counter):
    # Increment the counter 3 times.
    # Hold the counter's lock for read/modify/write operations.
    # Keep holding it so the value doesn't change before printing,
    # and keep prints from multiple processes from trying to write
    # to a line at the same time.
    for _ in range(3):
        with counter.get_lock():
            counter.value += 1
            print(mp.current_process().name,counter.value)

def main():
    counter = mp.Value('i') # shared integer
    processes = [mp.Process(target=process,args=(counter,)) for i in range(3)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Process-2 1
Process-2 2
Process-1 3
Process-3 4
Process-2 5
Process-1 6
Process-3 7
Process-1 8
Process-3 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You've only given part of your code, so I can only see a *potential* problem.  It doesn't do any good to lock-protect *one* access to `es_id`.  You must lock-protect them *all*, anywhere they occur in the program.  Perhaps it is best to create an access function for this purpose, like:

```
def increment_es_id():
    global es_id
    lock.acquire()
    es_id += 1
    lock.release()
```

This can be called safely from any thread.

In your code, it's a good practice to move the acquire/release calls as close together as you can make them.  Here you only need to protect one variable, so you can move the acquire/release pair to just before and after the `es_id += 1` statement..

Even better is to use the lock in a context manager (although in this simple case it won't make any difference):

```
def increment_es_id2():
    global es_id
    with lock:
        es_id += 1
```

Comment: According to your code, I think threads can reference the same value. But I want to prevent one thread from accessing another thread while refferring to ES_ID. The whole code is too long, so I added only the main code in post. saveDB is called after several other function

Comment: OP is using `multiprocessing`, not `threading` so there will be different instances of the global variable.  This won't work.